# Spiritual Weapon Range vs. LOS

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, ranged-attack

There's plenty of discussion and even sage advice out there explaining that a caster need not have Line of Sight (LOS) on a target for their Spiritual Weapon to make an attack. I.e. a paladin can summon their SW and leave the room and still be able to make attacks with the weapon.

But is this still the case for maintaining concentration on the spell if you leave the range of the spell?

Another way to phrase the question might be is the range of the spell only a determinate in the initial casting of the spell, or is the range the max "leash" of the spell to keep it active?

Comment: Also, welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/tour) if you haven't already, and check out the [help center](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/help) for more guidance. Good Luck and Happy Gaming!

Comment: Sorry about that, I added the edition. It's 5e D&D. And I think I may have just answered my own question with the Players Handbook. "Once a spell is cast, its effects aren’t limited by its range, unless the spell’s description says otherwise."

Comment: Please let us know if that doesn't answer your question. If it doesn't, what's missing? We can absolutely reopen if you are asking something different.